# In ER Diagram how can we represent a relation like some players are coaches or some students are teachers

Tags: sql, entity-relationship, erd

Teachers and Students are two separate entities how can we represent this relation.

Comment: You need at least two more tables.

Comment: can u please explain in detail.

Comment: I'm less willing to write novels than you are to type out all three letters of a word.

Answer (score 0):

you require 3 relations : one for teacher with attributes like name,age,phone,mail and id, one for student with attributes like name,id,age,parents' name,marks and mail and one for teaches with attributes as PK of above relations and other fields like subject and class timings and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a table for

```
PERSON
----------
person_id
name
birth_date
etc.
```

Then one for

```
SCHOOL
---------
school_id
name
etc.
```

and now link them up.

```
STUDENT
-------------
person_id
school_id
begin_date
end_date

TEACHER
-------------
person_id
school_id
begin_date
end_date
etc.
```